# Binding Button to a command in ViewModel in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have looked up couple of similar posts but they are all on WPF and I could not quite figure out how to bind the button inside a datagrid to the view model. I have tried something like below:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}"
.
.
. 
<Button 
  Command="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"
  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<MyClass> DeleteCommand { get; }
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Items { get; }
```

Code Behind:

```
public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; }

public MyPage()
{
  ViewModel = new ViewModel();
  this.DataContext = ViewModel;
  this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Do you have an element named DataGrid in your Visual Tree? And if you have it, what's the DataContext of it? It would be better if you'd provided your ViewModel / code behind as well

Comment: @Gleb Updated with ViewModel & code behind for the bindings and data context.

Comment: what about DataGrid? Do you really have a DataGrid named "DataGrid" as `<DataGrid Name="DataGrid"/>`?

Comment: yes sorry forgot to mention that, I have the element named as `DataGrid`

Comment: Are the Items defined at the same class that DeleteCommand? I'm confused with the fact that you're binding your items to DataContext.ViewModel.Items but your command to DataContext.DeleteCommand. Does your ViewModel class have ViewModel property?

Comment: @Gleb Sorry If I sound confusing, just recently started on UWP. So I have a ViewModel `MyViewModel` which contains the collection of items and the command as well. DataGrid is now bound to this items. Now inside the data grid I have a button which I am trying to bind to the view model command.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would do something like this.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- Your biuld-in button -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- Your other columns -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public Class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Items { get; }

    public RelayCommand<MyClass> DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<MyClass>((o) =>
                {
                    // ...
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```